# Is it possible offload a string array to Xeon Phi

Tags: c, xeon-phi

I want to get all substring of a string on xeon phi 
First, I read a txt file from args and store it into a pointer array like this

```
char *temp_string[N_ELEMENT];
```

Second, I want to using pragma offlad to copt this array to xeon phi like this

```
#pragma offload target(mic: 0) in(temp_string:length(N_ELEMENT))
```

The command line give me the following message

```
error: variable "temp_string" used in in/out/inout clause is an array whose underlying type is "char *"
```

Is it have any solutation to fix my problem?

---

The offload section like this:

```
#pragma offload target(mic: 0) in(temp_string:length(N_ELEMENT))
#pragma omp parallel for private(c, i, length)
for(n = 0; n < N_ELEMENT; ++n) 
{
    length = strlen(temp_string[n]);

    for( c = 0 ; c < length ; c++ )
        for( i = 1 ; i <= length - c ; i++ )
        {
            sub = substring(temp_string[n], c+1, i);
            printf("%s \n", sub);
        }

}
```

Comment: can you post some code of where you use temp_string in the offload section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is storing the strings in a flat `char* temp_string` pairing it with an index vector `int* vIndexes` that keeps the start index of each string.

Check this example taken from **[here](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/GUID-EAB414FD-40C6-4054-B094-0BA70824E2A2.htm)**. It represents all the cases for using `offload` section.

```
typedef int ARRAY[10][10]; 
int a[1000][500];
int *p;
ARRAY *q;
int *r[10][10];
int i, j;
struct { int y; } x;
#pragma offload …  in( a )
#pragma offload … out( a[i:j][:] )
#pragma offload …  in( p[0:100] )
#pragma offload …  in( (*q)[5][:] )
#pragma offload …  in( r[5][5][0:2] )
#pragma offload … out( x.y )
```

In all cases, the size of the block to be transfered can be determined at compile time. Check cases with `*q` and `*r`. In your case, the size of each element in temp_string cannot be determined. So I would try my first proposed solution.

Since I don't have a XeonPhi, I can't try it, but I would also try:

```
typedef char CHAR_ARRAY[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
CHAR_ARRAY temp_string[N_ELEMENTS];
#pragma offload target(mic: 0) in(temp_string)
```

The advantage of the first solution is that it is fully dynamic and transfers the exact same amount of data as you need. The second solution would allow the compiler to properly align your structure and make better use of vectorization.

Comment: I'm not sure that I know what you mean, can you give me some example to hint me how to solve my problem? Thanks very much.

Comment: error: variable "temp_string" used in in/out/inout clause is an array whose underlying type is "char *"
  #pragma offload target(mic: 0) in(temp_string:length[N_ELEMENT][0:26])

Comment: internal error: assertion failed: for_statement: expected for (shared/cfe/edgcpfe/statements.c, line 5575)

Comment: Try and remove "length". Use it like this: in(temp_string[N_ELEMENT][0:26])

Comment: error: variable "temp_string" used in in/out/inout clause is an array whose underlying type is "char *"
  #pragma offload target(mic: 0) in(temp_string[N_ELEMENT][0:26])